# Using a level of indirection in a template SFINAE constraint causes a hard error

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17, sfinae

In the following code (https://wandbox.org/permlink/rA7lnXM6eQR4JhSM)

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct Identity : public T {};

class Something {
public:
  Something() = default;
  Something(const Something&) = delete;
  Something(Something&&) = default;
  Something& operator=(const Something&) = default;
  Something& operator=(Something&&) = default;

  template <
      typename T,
      typename U = std::decay_t<T>,
      std::enable_if_t<Identity<
        std::is_constructible<U, T&&>>::value>* = nullptr>
  explicit Something(T&&) {};
};

int main() {
    static_cast<void>(std::is_constructible<Something, const Something&>{});
}
```

I get the following error

```
error: base class has incomplete type
struct Identity : public T {};
                  ~~~~~~~^
```

The error goes away when I remove the indirection with `Identity` in the constraint to this (https://wandbox.org/permlink/MFJCHUzeKnS4yR0d)

```
  template <
      typename T,
      typename U = std::decay_t<T>,
      std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_constructible<U, T&&>::value>* = nullptr>
  explicit Something(T&&) {};
```

From my understanding, the issue here was that we are trying to instantiate `std::is_constructible`, which then instantiates the constructor for `Something`, which then in turn instantiates `std::is_constructible`, and so on.

But why does the error go away when I try to compile this without `Identity`? And why does it error out when I use `Identity`?

Comment: `is_constructible_v` comes since C++17, just for simplifying code

Comment: off the top of my head: `std::is_constructible` does not inherit from either of its arguments, so it operates on different constraints than your Identity class.

Answer (score 1):

You’ve already worked out that there is a “recursive instantiation”.  There’s no real recursion; what happens in the case that “works” is simply that, when considering the constructor template to find out whether the construction from a `const Something&` would succeed, `std::is_constructible<Something, const Something&>` has no member `value` **yet**.  (Contrary to popular belief, a class `C` need not be complete to name a member with `C::`—but the named member must have already been declared, and the exact meaning of “already” is [a bit murky](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#287).)

That error is in the **immediate context** of the constructor template, so the template is silently ignored.  (This makes no difference in this case: the (deleted) copy constructor is a better match since it’s not a template.)  This establishes that the very `value` that was missing is `false`, which is at least **consistent** with having rejected the constructor template the first time.  This may be in violation of [[meta.rqmts]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta.rqmts#5) for the very specialization of `std::is_constructible` itself; consider that hilarity ensues if we negate the condition in an `enable_if` that controls itself.

Your `Identity` encounters the same error (or the more general issue of the relevant specialization not yet being complete).  Being part of a subsidiary instantiation, the error is unrecoverable.

Comment: Does this also mean that [meta.unary.prop]/Table 47, regarding completeness pre-conditions on the template parameters of `std::is_constructible`, that _"`T` and all types in the parameter pack `Args` shall be complete types"_, is violated (in both examples)?

Comment: @dfri: No—the default template argument isn’t instantiated until needed, when `Something` is long complete.

Comment: Not sure I follow, why then does the error remain if I don't inherit from it and use the value member directly - https://wandbox.org/permlink/i6LGLny3KpuAKslY?

Comment: @Curious: I overemphasized the completeness issue, sorry.  The lookup for `value` fails just as much as the inheritance *while* `is_constructible` is being instantiated, and is just as much outside the immediate context.  I’ve added more explanatory detail and will rephrase to avoid confusion about completeness.